# OK Cancel dialog after clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a beginner with jquery an do not know how to proceed with my project. 
What I want to do is to create a dialog box with two buttons OK and Cancel that would pop up after clicking on a link.
I have fully working example but the problem with it is that I do not like the dialog (example A).
I have also nice dialog box (example B), but I do not know how to integrate it with a link.
Can anybody help me with this please?

Here is code example A - fully working but not nice :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Usuwanie produktu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>




</script>

</head>
<body>


<a href="delete.php?id=22" class="confirmation">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.confirmation').on('click', function () {
        return confirm('Czy jesteś pewien, że chcesz usunąć wybrany produkt?');
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code example B - a nice looking dialog with two buttons OK and Cancel, but without link integration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>Usuwanie produktu</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
$( function() {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        window.location.href = "glowny.php?akcja=produkty";
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                }
        });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie produktu">
        <p>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
                Wybrany produkt został pomyślnie usunięty z bazy danych.
        </p>
        <p>
                Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
        </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am sure this is not too difficult, but I do not have the knowledge that would be sufficient to complete the task.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$("#dialog-message").hide();
$('.confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        window.location.href = "glowny.php?akcja=produkty";
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Usuwanie produktu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie produktu">
    <p>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>Wybrany produkt został pomyślnie usunięty z bazy danych.
    </p>
    <p>
      Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
    </p>
  </div>
  <a href="delete.php?id=22" class="confirmation">Link</a>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I did copied the html code and put jquery code in the script part - and it works partially, I mean dialog comes up but there are no messages in there. When I add messages to html part then the dialog box came up as expected with its contents, but the same contents appeared on the page. This is a problem. I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: It looks really great! It works. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: If it helped you up-vote and mark it as correct so that it can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You were near to your objective. Your dialog in example B, need a property autoOpen set to false. It will block the dialog to open when the document load.

Then to do like the Example A, trigger the modal opening. Just create an event on clicking on the element.

```
  $("#link").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
      })
```

Code Snippest below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Usuwanie produktu</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
          Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            window.location.href = "glowny.php?akcja=produkty";
          },
          Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });
      $("#link").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog("open");
      })

    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <p id="link"> click on me to open</p>
  <div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie produktu">
    <p>
      <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span> Wybrany produkt został pomyślnie usunięty z bazy danych.
    </p>
    <p>
      Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I copied the code but I did not get a link working. dialog also did not came up.

Comment: Open the development tool by pressing F12. Do you have any error message in the console tab ? 
I copy paste and try on various browser (chrom,ie,firefox), and on my side i didn't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by  Ashay Mandwarya works fine for me.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <title>Usuwanie produktu</title> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> </head>

<body> <div id="dialog-message" title="Usuwanie produktu">
        <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>Wybrany produkt został pomyślnie usunięty z bazy danych.
        </p>
        <p>
        Naciśnij OK aby kontynuować.
        </p> </div>

<a href="delete.php?id=22" class="confirmation">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#dialog-message").hide();
        $('.confirmation').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location.href = "glowny.php?akcja=produkty";
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                }
        }); });

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thank you all for yours replays and help.